# Setting default JRE on OS X

Tags: java, macos

Some background: OS X is, for the most part, foreign to me. I am trying to update to Java 8 to run something I made.

OS X 10.9.4.

It had/has Java version 1.6. I wish to update to Java 8. The subversion thereof is not specifically needed, but the most recent will do. The version I was looking at was the Oracle one. As aforementioned, my knowledge of OS X is lacking, but it is my understanding that Apple previously implemented their own, which may be the reason for some of the problems now.

It seemed to install correctly. System Preferences > Java > Java Control Panel shows the desired version - 8 11. The terminal, however, displays 1.6.

It seems on OS X there are a plethora of potential java locations - some concrete, some symbolic. In /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions, there are several versions spanning 1.4-1.6, but nothing more recent. I cannot find any concrete location where 1.8 may reside.

How can I set the default JRE to this 1.8 update?

EDIT:

I found the 1.8 JRE in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

Comment: What are the directories beneath `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`? Do you need a full SDK or just JRE?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html):

> To run a different version of Java, either specify the full path, or use the java_home tool:
>
> `% /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_06 --exec javac -version`
>
> For more information, see the java_home(1) man page.

My current version of java resides in: `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: java_home finds no 1.8 version, and lists a 1.6 version with the other arguments. The JavaVirtualMachines folder appears to be empty. Note this is an updated JRE, not a JDK, as I only plan to run things.

Comment: As noted on Oracle's Java OS X FAQ:  Installing a JRE from Oracle does not update java -version symlinks or add the java command to your path. For this functionality, you must install the full JDK. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_install_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to handle this issue... but to answer your question about JRE see below.

1.) Bash Profile

*If your not pointing to the JRE, your putting the JDK on your class path. For Java developers using a java tools / compiler, you want the JDK. If your looking for JRE this is more correct.*

```
vi ~/.bash_profile (or) ~/.bashrc (to append the export)

export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre:$PATH
```

*I'm not sure if Apple will change their ways, but this is a safe method for individual users.*

2.) Setting /Java

```
Configure this same address MAC -> Setting -> Java -> Java Tab -> View -> User or System -> Path
```